# Avoid redundancy

Tags: duplicates, python-3.6

Here is a portion of my code.

```
if deplacement_result == "ok":
    if self.current_player_color == "white":
        self.current_player_color = "black"
    else:
        self.current_player_color = "white"

elif deplacement_result == "taking":
    if self.damier.can_take_the_piece(target_position):
        self.forced_source_position = target_position
    else:
        self.forced_source_position = None
        self.have_to_take = False

        if self.current_player_color == "white":
            self.current_player_color = "black"
        else:
            self.current_player_color = "white"
```

I noticed I have twice the code

```
if self.current_player_color == "white":
    self.current_player_color = "black"
else:
    self.current_player_color = "white"
```

How can I avoid repeating myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the sake of avoiding code repetition per your question,
You can use a flag variable.

```py
switch_color = False
if deplacement_result == "ok":
    switch_color = True

elif deplacement_result == "taking":
    if self.damier.can_take_the_piece(target_position):
        self.forced_source_position = target_position
    else:
        self.forced_source_position = None
        self.have_to_take = False
        switch_color = True

if switch_color:
    if self.current_player_color == "white":
        self.current_player_color = "black"
    else:
        self.current_player_color = "white"
    switch_color = False
```

Comment: I think you will have to `switch_color` to `False` once you have switch the color in the `if switch_color:` statement

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce it to a single line.

```
self.couleur_joueur_courant = "noir" if self.couleur_joueur_courant == "blanc" else "blanc"
```

Comment: you assign 'noir' in both cases (fyi)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rid of the redundancy, you can try using this:

```py
if resultat_deplacement == "ok" or resultat_deplacement == "prise":
    # This code is executed in either case
    if self.couleur_joueur_courant == "blanc":
        self.couleur_joueur_courant = "noir"
    else:
        self.couleur_joueur_courant = "blanc"

    if resultat_deplacement == "prise":  # Only executes for the if this is True
        if self.damier.piece_peut_faire_une_prise(position_cible):
            self.position_source_forcee = position_cible
        else:
            self.position_source_forcee = None
            self.doit_prendre = False
```

But as pointed out @chessguy, this repeats the if statement twice.

You can try defining a function like this (and convert to French if required):

```py
def setColour():
    if self.couleur_joueur_courant == "blanc":
        self.couleur_joueur_courant = "noir"
    else:
        self.couleur_joueur_courant = "blanc"

if resultat_deplacement == "ok":
    setColour()

if resultat_deplacement == "prise":  # Only executes for the if this is True
    setColour()
    if self.damier.piece_peut_faire_une_prise(position_cible):
        self.position_source_forcee = position_cible
    else:
        self.position_source_forcee = None
        self.doit_prendre = False
```

Comment: Not that better because you repeat the condition `resultat_deplacement == 'prise'`

Comment: hmmm.. would you want to define a function and do this? I'll add it to the answer

Answer (score 0):

in your code, you do not need `else` part, since it it re-initializing to same string. Only following code will suffice:

```
if self.current_player_color == "white":
    self.current_player_color = "black"
```

in place of thiss:

```
if self.current_player_color == "white":
    self.current_player_color = "black"
else:
    self.current_player_color = "white"
```

Or, you can use a one liner:

```
self.couleur_joueur_courant = "noir" if self.couleur_joueur_courant == "blanc"
```

Comment: No, when `self.current_player_color == "black"` the value should be changed to `"white"`. So it doesn't work.

Comment: @ywbaek Do you have a suggestion of an answer?

Comment: @chessguy maybe use a flag variable like `self.switch_color = False`?

Comment: @ywbaek None of the three attempts  really answer my question. If you can make a full answer, it might help me